# How to calculate total expense of common items in a list of tuples in Python?

Tags: python

From the below list of tuples I need to create a list of tuples such that:

```
input=[('bread', '    1.90'), ('bread ', ' 1.95'), ('chips ', '    2.54'), ('milk', '2.35'), ('milk', '2.31'), ('milk  ', '    2.38')]

out=[('bread', '$3.85'), ('chips', '$2.54'), ('milk', '$7.04')]
```

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: yes, sorted names and total amount

Comment: Do you have any code? What have you tried?

Comment: Same question and data: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35973849/2087463

Answer (score 2):

One `for` loop and one list comprehension can do it:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dictionary = OrderedDict()
for key, value in input:
    key = key.strip()
    dictionary[key] = dictionary.setdefault(key, 0) + float(value)

out = [(key, "${}".format(value)) for key, value in dictionary.items()]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, You are awesome!! Thanks again!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the gray check mark below the vote count.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your list of tuples and add them to a dictionary. After that you can create your resulting list of t

```
input = [('bread', '    1.90'), ('bread ', ' 1.95'), ('chips ', '    2.54'), ('milk', '2.35'), ('milk', '2.31'), ('milk  ', '    2.38')]

# Create dictionary from list of tuples
out_dict = {}
for item, value in input:
    item_name = item.rstrip()
    if item_name not in out_dict:
        out_dict[item_name] = float(value)
    else:
        out_dict[item_name] += float(value)

# Create list of tuples from dictionary
out = []
for item in out_dict:
    out.append((item, '${:.2f}'.format(out_dict[item])))

print(out)
```

This prints:

> [('bread', '$3.85'), ('milk', '$7.04'), ('chips', '$2.54')]

Comment: perfect!!,Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by following code:

```
def calculate_expenses(filename):
    file_pointer = open(filename, 'r')
    # You can use either .read() or .readline() or .readlines()
    data = file_pointer.readlines()
    # NOW CONTINUE YOUR CODE FROM HERE!!!

    my_dictionary = {}
    for line in data:
        item, price= line.strip().split(',')

        my_dictionary[item.strip()] = my_dictionary.get(item.strip(),0) + float(price)
    dic={}
    for k,v in my_dictionary.items():
        dic[k]='${0:.2f}'.format(round(v,2))

    L=([(k,v) for k, v in dic.iteritems()])
    L.sort()

    return L
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_data = [("bread", "    1.90"), ("bread", "   1.95"), ("chips", "  2.54"),
             ("milk", "2.35"), ("milk", "2.31"), ("milk", "  2.38")]

TL = [] # A list
print(input_data)
for item, price in input_data:
    if item in TL:
        # converting 'str' values to 'float' and adding them and storing them 
        # back as a 'str' at the same index
        TL[TL.index(item)+1] = str(float(TL[TL.index(item)+1]) + float(price))
    else:
        TL += item, price

input_data = TL
print(input_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> l=[('bread', '    1.90'), ('bread ', ' 1.95'), ('chips ', '    2.54'), ('milk', '2.35'), ('milk', '2.31'), ('milk  ', '    2.38')]
>>>
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> d = defaultdict(float)
>>> for k,v in l:
        d[k.strip()] += float(v.strip())


>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {'chips': 2.54, 'milk': 7.04, 'bread': 3.8499999999999996})
>>> out = [(k, '${:.2f}'.format(v)) for k,v in sorted(d.items())]
>>> out
[('bread', '$3.85'), ('chips', '$2.54'), ('milk', '$7.04')]
```