# To input a file and get a formatted string output using .format()

Tags: python, file-io

Write a function named `calculate_expenses` that receives a filename as argument. The file contains the information about a person's expenses on items. Your function should return a list of tuples sorted based on the name of the items. Each tuple consists of the name of the item and total expense of that item as shown below:

[image]

Notice that each line of the file only includes an item and the purchase price of that item separated by a comma. There may be spaces before or after the item or the price. Then your function should read the file and return a list of tuples such as:

[image]

Notes:

- Tuples are sorted based on the item names i.e. bread comes before chips which comes before milk.
- The total expenses are strings which start with a $ and they have two digits of accuracy after the decimal point.

Hint: Use `${:.2f}` to properly create and format strings for the total expenses.

The code so far:

```
def calculate_expenses(file_name):
file_pointer = open(file_name, 'r')
data = file_pointer.readlines()
list_main=[]
for line in data:
    name, price = line.strip().split(',')
    print (name, price)
```

Output:

```
('milk', '2.35')
('bread ', ' 1.95')
('chips ', '    2.54')
('milk  ', '    2.38')
('milk', '2.31')
('bread', '    1.90')
```

I can't get rid of the spaces and don't know what to do next.

Comment: `print(name.strip(), price.strip())`

Comment: `print (name, price.strip())`

Comment: You asked the same question 2 hours ago...

Comment: Add your code as code, not as image.

Comment: [This is a question to ask google](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+remove+extra+whitespace+from+string)

Comment: Other question, same prices for the same stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35960341/5276734

Comment: You have to convert the price to a float.

Comment: [homework alert](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812) :)

Comment: You used `strip` once, do you see how to use it again with the above comments? After that you will want to [google this](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+make+string+a+number) then [google this](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+how+to+add+numbers+in+tuple).  Welcome to programming!  You need to take general examples and figure out how to connected them together to build the specifics you need.  Don't panic and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Can be solved by :

```
def calculate_expenses(filename):
    file_pointer = open(filename, 'r')
    # You can use either .read() or .readline() or .readlines()
    data = file_pointer.readlines()
    # NOW CONTINUE YOUR CODE FROM HERE!!!

    my_dictionary = {}
    for line in data:
        item, price= line.strip().split(',')

        my_dictionary[item.strip()] = my_dictionary.get(item.strip(),0) + float(price)
    dic={}
    for k,v in my_dictionary.items():
        dic[k]='${0:.2f}'.format(round(v,2))

    L=([(k,v) for k, v in dic.iteritems()])
    L.sort()

    return L
```

Answer (score 0):

in python3 we haven't "iteritems".
you should use "item" in this line:

```
L=([(k,v) for k, v in dic.iteritems()])
```